# Can't Write the the device storage Android 10 Build 10.0.0183

Tags: android, storage, android-10.0

My application stop to create files to the device storage on Android 10 Build 10.0.0183 although I put write storage permission in the manifest file

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and request permission programmatically

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this.getActivity(),
            PERMS_TAKE_PICTURE,
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
```

I notes also that the app folder didn't create

```
 String appPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + 
 "Android" + File.separator + "data" + File.separator + mContext.getPackageName() + File.separator + 
 "files"
```

Although the app works good on Android 9, please help

Comment: This may help. https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/07/death-external-storage-end-saga.html

Comment: Thanks a alot ..